# How to disable automatic Flash Player updates in Chrome?

Tags: apache-flex, google-chrome, flash

Does anyone know how you can disable the automatic updating of Flash Player that comes installed with Chrome? The problem is that when you disable it (because you want to enable a manually installed one) it is re-enabled each time Chrome updates.

As a developer this is very annoying since a debug player is replaced with a non-debug player. It is also an issue if you want your users to use a specific version of Flash Player instead of the built-in one.

I can find information about disabling the built-in plugin [1], but not about disabling the automatic updates.

[1] http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=108086

Comment: What about removing the plugin .dll at C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\<appnumber>\PepperFlash\pepflashplayer.dll this should get rid of the preinstalled plugin altogether?

Comment: I have not tried that, but I would assume it will be re-installed on the next Chrome update.

Comment: cfr. http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/GXhQPBQ1v60

Comment: Thanks Dennis. I didn't know about that option.

Answer (score 0):

I use Chrome on the dev channel (for OSX), and when I receive updates, Pepper Flash remains disabled.

http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel